# Using a Workflow Rule to notify of Contact changes

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow

Is there a way to create a workflow rule to send an email every time a contact's last name change or home address changes?  Or would I need to create a trigger for this?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a workflow rule to do this. You would need to fire the workflow rule anytime a record is "created, and anytime it's edited" and the use the IsChanged() formula to look at the LastName or any of the address fields. The workflow action you can take is an email message.

I would argue that this type of email notification is a huge overkill and will create noise to the point of being completely unusable.  You might just consider enabling Field History tracking for the fields you wish to track and reporting on that regularly.

Comment: Interesting.  thank you Green.  I do have field history tracking on these fields but how could I report these on a regular basis.  would that be setting a scheduled report on these fields? and how would the reports let me know a last name has changed?

Comment: Contact History reports have a New Value and Old Value field and those history records are only created when a value has changed. You could then schedule this report.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this through a workflow.  You would want the WFR to evaluate each time a record is created or edited.  You would also want to change your rule criteria to a formula and use

```
ISCHANGED(LastName)
```

**You can see a shot of the WFR below.**

[image]

Then you can set up a workflow action of an email alert.

You would have to set up a second rule for the address change, but the same rationale applies.  Or you could use filter logic and use the same WFR rule for address change OR last name change, but that is up to you.

Comment: @WickWack If that answered your query please mark the answer as answered .That will help others .